# Is it possible in python to process addresses that are written in various formats and build a map?

Tags: python, analysis

There is data in which the addresses are listed (there may be typos) in various formats, somewhere it is written c. New York, street ......, somewhere the city of New York to one format and build, for example, a tableau map. How to do it?

Comment: Hello, could you list what have you already tried and why it didn't work? Depending on your data and your actual needs there could be several posible solutions. For example, you can look the `re` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev problem is that I have a different format address and I have no one template

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use modules as [smartstreets.py](https://pypi.org/project/smartystreets.py/) for validating directions and getting the cordenates using an "api"